# Rough transparent Plastic Material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, transparency

I am trying to recreate the [FN P90](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FN_P90) submachine gun. I followed a tutorial on modelling and UV unwrapping. Now I tried adding procedural Textures to it.

As you can see, the [clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yfmr.jpg) is made up of a rough transparent plastic material:

[image]

The clip is a model with an inside with correct normals so the refraction works. On here I saw others use a mix shader with some Gloss and Diffuse to make it less glassy. But that did not really work. Is my factory to high? Here is the shader I used:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For basic materials like plastic, glass and metal, you only need Principled BSDF.
Rough plastic has similar properties as rough glass.

1. Transmission = 1
2. Roughness = 0,2
3. That's it.

[image]
[image]