# How do I get a tinted translucent material?

Tags: materials

How do I get a translucent material like the one in this image that clearly shows what is inside?

[image]

I need a material that can be tinted and also overlapped to create a darker color.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Subsurface Scattering maybe. Transparency.

Comment: Related: [How to make translucent plastic material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/214833/78972)

Answer (score 6):

You could use the Translucent BSDF, but it's really limited to that aspect only and needs to be mixed with other basic shaders like glass or glossy BSDFs to give more complete results.

Instead, I like to use the Principled BSDF for this:

[image]

- *Base Color* for the... base color
- *Roughness* will impact the reflections' roughness
- *Transmission* will determine how much you can see through the shader
- *Transmission Roughness* kind of blurs what you see through the shader.

I got this result by quickly modeling three cylinders, one for the ink, one for the ink cartridge and a last one for the pen. Each with different values for the above four settings.

---

If it's a shader you use often, you could make a Node Group out of it. Select the Principled BSDF in the shader editor, hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to turn it into a group, <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> inside it, select the Group Input and remove all the inputs you don't need via the sidebar > Group tab > Inputs panel:

[image]

I would keep the Normal too, very useful if you want to add the depths of the labels prints.

<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> out of the group, give it a name and check the shield icon to make it persistent data, and now you can very quickly interact with that nodegroup or add it in another shader via <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> > Group:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: My pleasure. Don't hesitate to use the buttons in the top left corner of my answer to upvote it and mark it as the correct answer.